# How do i do a text-shadow zoom with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css, cross-browser

I would like to recreate the effect in this website's footer: http://desandro.com/ (hover over 'Desandro made this' in the bottom left corner.

Here they use CSS3 and text-shadow, but i wondered if this is doable with jQuery to allow it work work in all browsers?

Thanks.

Comment: This probably doesn't answer your question, but it indeed is a really nice effect! (I'ld recommend you to use the CSS3 way, it's far more stable and only IE9 isn't supporting it, Opera, FF, Chrome and Safari just do...)

Answer (score 0):

For cross browser cs3 shadow, gradients and rounded corner effects you can use http://css3pie.com/ actually CSS3 works in all latest browsers except IE7 and somehow IE8 so css3 pie.com is the solution for IEs. ;)

Comment: If something can easily be done then don't make it complex, I mean adding jquery you will have to fix cross browser's rendering issues and it will also slows down when page will be in downloading process.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this

solutions:

1. you don,t need jquery for this. just create class, and use Class_name:hover. it will 
     work. Reference website name given by you has not use jquery for this.
2. if you want jquery refer this, for examples:

   Html:

   ```
   <a href="#">
       <span>David</span>
       <span>DeSandro</span>
       <span>DeSandro</span>
       <span>DeSandro</span>  
   </a>
   ```

   jquery:

   ```
    $(document).ready(
       $(a).hover(
          function(){
             $(this).children().eq(0).addclass('style1');
             $(this).children().eq(1).addclass('style2');
             $(this).children().eq(2).addclass('style3');
             $(this).children().eq(3).addclass('style4');
         },
         function(){ 
             $(this).children().eq(0).removeclass('style1');
             $(this).children().eq(1).removeclass('style2');
             $(this).children().eq(2).removeclass('style3');
             $(this).children().eq(3).removeclass('style4');
         });
    );
   ```

I am not sure whether IE browser support this CSS